# Simple Servlet Question on ServletConfig instantiation

Tags: java, servlets, servletconfig

Apparently the following is generating a loop(the `GenericServlet` class is calling the subclass's `init()`)

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

  ServletConfig c = this.getServletConfig();
  super.init(c);

}
```

I'm probably just doing this wrong. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `super.init(c);` line. You only need to call this in [`init(ServletConfig)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method, **not** in the [`init()` without `ServletConfig` argument](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29). That's also exactly what the linked javadoc tells:

> A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's **no need** to call `super.init(config)`.

The infinite loop is indeed caused because the default `init(config)` implementation is under the hoods calling the `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `super.init(c);`. Remove it.

Comment: False. It's the exact answer to OPs problem.